# (Python) manually copy/paste data from pandas table without copying the index

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking around but could not find an similar post, so I thought I'd give it a go.
I wrote an pandas program that sucessfully displays the resulting dataframe in pandas table format in a tkinter textbox. the aim is that the user can select the data ancopy/paste it into an (existing)excel sheet. when doing this, the index is always copied as well. I was wondering if one could programmatically select the complete table except the index?
I know that one can save to excel or other with index=false, but I could not find a kind of df.select....index=false. I hope my explanation is more or less clear ;-)
Thanks a lot
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZVPj.png)

Comment: Hi Serge, it would be helpful if you provided a minimal working example (python code) that those willing to help you can simply modify to point out the solution.

Comment: I added a screenshot. If I manually select the cells from top left to bottom right and copy paste them to Excel, the index is pasted as well. So I want to know if there is maybe a way to write some code that selects and copies this table so I can paste it to Excel without the index column.I tried with mytable.selectAll() but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it.
Instead of using something like `self.mytable.copy('columns')` to select everything and then switch to Excel and paste it, I use this line of code which does exactly what I need :

```
df.to_clipboard(sep="\t", index=False)
```

The sep="\t" makes it split up amongst columns in Excel.

Hopefully someone can use this at some stage.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you could use dataframe's 'to_string' function, here you could pass 'index = False' as one of the parameters. For Ex: say we have this df:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['yes', 'no', 'yes' ], 'b': [10,  5, 20]})
print(df.to_string(index = False))`

this would give you:

```
a    b
yes  10
no   5
yes  20
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I did that in the very beginning. The issue is that the output(I displayed it in a tkinter text widget) has no delimiters, and so if I paste it into excel,everyting is in one cell. So I would need to do a text to columns and I’m looking for a solution where the user has a little to manipulate as possible